# Launcher activity showing for an instant even if the session is active

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am making my LoginActivity as my Launcher activity. Here user tries to login by email-id and password which is stored in firebase. If user login successfully once, then he/she should remain into home page which is not launcher activity. I am doing this by putting onStart() method and checking by FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null. But the issue is that, when I stop the app from background ad open it again, then for fraction of seconds it shows launcher activity, and then opening the home page. I don't want to show my launcher activity for that instant and doesn't want to show them that it's getting transferred to new activity. Please help me that how to achieve this.

Comment: You should use a Splash screen for that.

Comment: If I don't want to use splash screen in my app then is there any solution?

Comment: Hi Shubham, I suggest you check Alex Mamo's profile. If you ever decide to go the splash screen route, here's a link https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565